# embedded linux: readdir() sometimes failing with EFAULT

Tags: linux, readdir

I've had some `readdir()` issues occur in an embedded app, so I added this self-contained test at a convenient place in the app code:

```
FILE *f;
DIR *d;

f = fopen ("/mnt/mydir/myfile", "r");
printf ("fopen %p\r\n", f);
if (f) fclose(f);

d = opendir ("/mnt/mydir");
printf ("opendir ret %p\r\n", f);
if (d)
{
    struct dirent *entry;
    do
    {
    errno = 0;
    entry = readdir (d);
    printf ("readdir ret %p %s, errno %d %s\r\n", entry, entry ? entry->d_name : "", errno, strerror(errno));
    } while (entry);
    closedir (d);
}
```

`/mnt/mydir` is an NFS mount (although I'm not sure if that's relevant). The `fopen()` call to open a file in that dir always succeeds, and the `opendir()` on the dir also always succeeds. However, sometimes (most) the `readdir()` fails with `errno=EFAULT`.

I don't believe anywhere else in the app is doing anything with that dir. The test is exactly as written, all variables are local stack scope.

If I run it as a standalone program, it always succeeds.

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to what could cause EFAULT here? I'm pretty sure my DIR pointer variable is not being corrupted, although the DIR structure itself could be I guess. I haven't seen any evidence elsewhere of heap corruption.

Comment: AFAICT, that's not a valid return from `readdir()`. Does your (non-standalone) code really reset `errno` prior to calling `readdir()`? Could anything else be setting it either before or after the call? Also which libc are you using?

Comment: Yes I'm explicitly resetting errno on each call. Using uClibc for ARM.

Comment: Is your program multithreaded? I'm not entirely sure, but it looks like some older versions of uClibc (possibly using linuxthreads) don't  make `errno` thread local. see https://bugs.uclibc.org/2089 and http://lists.uclibc.org/pipermail/uclibc/2010-July/044196.html

Comment: It is multithreaded. I'm not sure of the exact uClibc version, but I believe it's reasonably up-to-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem. The uClibc implementation of opendir/readdir does a stat() on the directory, then later does a stack alloca() of size statbuf.st_blksize. My NFS directory was mounted with rsize=512KB, causing readdir() to try and allocate 512KB on the stack to hold the dents. My embedded setup does not have that much room between stacks, so at some point was hitting something below in memory and causing EFAULT.

If I change my NFS mount options to rsize=4096, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

From `man 2 readdir` page:

```
       EFAULT Argument points outside the calling process's address space.
```

This means that your structure is corrupted

Comment: That's my thought too, but I can't imagine what's corrupting it, or why everything else appears to be fine. I will do some more digging.